# Write ls to array (split by newline)

Tags: bash, ls, array

I want my directory listing output in an array.

```
readarray x < <( ls -la )
printf "%s" ${x[@]}
```

So I wrote this, which works but it splits by space and not by newline. I can't find a "newline" parameter at readarray manual, so I'm kind of curious if there is a neat way to solve that request.
Please do not suggest to use `find` (I am restricted to use `ls -la`).

I use bash 4.3.

Comment: The splitting is occurring in the printing, not in the reading I think: see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters), in particular the section `Why do I need to write "$foo"? What happens without the quotes?`

Comment: Possible duplicate of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884992/how-do-i-assign-ls-to-an-array-in-linux-bash

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you for the suggestion. Putting the second argument of printf into quotes seems to change things. I would accept your answer, if you add it.

Comment: @voidspacexyz No, this is not a duplicate. Please consider that I am *restricted* to use ls -la. When using the method you've linked then it would look like this: `x=($(ls -la))` which results in split words and not split lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does read by line, but you forgot to quote `${x[@]}` which meant the split+glob operator was applied to it.

```
readarray x < <(ls -la)
printf %s "${x[@]}"
```

Or to remove the last newline character from each of those lines:

```
readarray -t x < <(ls -la)
printf 'line: %s\n' "${x[@]}"
```

Or using the *split+glob* operator:

```
IFS=$'\n' # split on newline
set -o noglob
x=($(ls -la))
```

(contrary to `readarray -t`, that method removes empty lines though (unlikely though not impossible to occur in the output of `ls -la`))

If you wanted to have the list of files names (including hidden ones) without the other `ls -l` information, you'd rather use:

```
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
x=(*)
```

Contrary to `ls -a`, it doesn't include `.` nor `..` though. If you really wanted them, you'd do instead:

```
shopt -s nullglob
x=(.* *)
```